# Corosync cluster will not bind vips to loopback, so apache fails to start in CentOS 7

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, corosync, loopback, lvs

I have a problem getting apache to work in a corosync cluster.

I probably sifted through more than hundred web pages and a couple of dozen Google Searches, and was not able to find any matching answer on my issue.

```
root@hh1web03t ~# uname -a
Linux hh1web03t 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 25 20:13:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@hh1web03t ~# more /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
root@hh1web03t ~# yum list installed corosync httpd crmsh ldirectord
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
 * epel: mirror.speedpartner.de
 * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * updates: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
Installed Packages
corosync.x86_64        2.4.0-9.el7_4.2             @updates
crmsh.noarch           3.0.0-6.2                   @network_ha-clustering_Stable
httpd.x86_64           2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6       @updates
ldirectord.x86_64      3.9.6-0rc1.1.2              @network_ha-clustering_Stable
```

We have 4 physical IPs and 10 vips. crm status looks like this:

```
root@hh1web03t ~# crm status

Stack: corosync
Current DC: hh1web03t (version 1.1.16-12.el7_4.7-94ff4df) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Thu Mar 29 15:53:27 2018
Last change: Thu Mar 29 15:28:47 2018 by hacluster via crmd on hh1web01t

4 nodes configured
16 resources configured

Online: [ hh1web01t hh1web02t hh1web03t hh1web04t ]

Full list of resources:

 pingd  (ocf::pacemaker:ping):  Started hh1web03t
 Resource Group: gp_LVS
     ldirectord (ocf::heartbeat:ldirectord):    Started hh1web03t
     vip_151    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_152    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_153    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_154    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_155    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_156    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_157    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_158    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_159    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
     vip_160    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started hh1web03t
 Clone Set: cl_vip151 [vip_151_apache]
     Started: [ hh1web01t hh1web02t hh1web03t hh1web04t ]
```

But that is only with a "Listen 80"-statement in the "httpd.conf". As soon as I the the VIP to the Listen (Listen 10.49.4.151:80), the startup of the httpd fails.

From another cluster I know that the vips should be in standby on the "lo" loopback-interface, but they are not. So it is my assumption that my problem lies within my cluster configuration, and not the apache configuration.

Active Node:

```
root@hh1web03t ~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:aa:1d:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.49.4.103/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.151/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:151
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.152/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:152
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.153/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:153
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.154/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:154
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.155/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:155
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.156/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:156
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.157/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:157
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.158/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:158
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.159/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:159
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.49.4.160/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global secondary ens192:160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Standby Node:

```
root@hh1web04t ~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 100
    link/ether 00:50:56:aa:0c:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.49.4.104/24 brd 10.49.4.255 scope global ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is what telnet and netstat show:

```
root@hh1web03t ~# telnet 10.49.4.151 80
Trying 10.49.4.151...

root@hh1web03t ~# telnet 10.49.4.101 80
Trying 10.49.4.101...
Connected to 10.49.4.101.
Escape character is '^]'.


^C
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@hh1web03t ~#
root@hh1web03t ~# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3470/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1093/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3470/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::2224                 :::*                    LISTEN      818/ruby
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1093/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::6556                 :::*                    LISTEN      1098/xinetd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.160:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.159:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.158:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.157:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.156:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.155:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.154:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.153:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.152:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.151:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.103:123         0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           847/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.49.4.103:39328       0.0.0.0:*                           1165/corosync
udp        0      0 10.49.4.103:47882       0.0.0.0:*                           1165/corosync
udp        0      0 10.49.4.103:58219       0.0.0.0:*                           1165/corosync
udp        0      0 10.49.4.103:52173       0.0.0.0:*                           1165/corosync
udp        0      0 10.49.4.103:5409        0.0.0.0:*                           1165/corosync
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                847/ntpd
root@hh1web03t ~#
```

I can ssh into the VIP, which, in this scenario, will take me to host hh1web03t:

```
root@hh1web04t ~# ssh 10.49.4.151
Last login: Thu Mar 29 16:19:39 2018 from hh1web03t
root@hh1web03t ~#
```

Here is the section of crm configure show, please note lvs_support is set to true:

```
primitive vip_151 IPaddr2 \
        params ip=10.49.4.151 cidr_netmask=24 iflabel=151 nic=ens192 lvs_support=true \
        meta target-role=Started \
        op monitor interval=30s
primitive vip_151_apache apache \
        params httpd="/usr/sbin/httpd" options="-d /etc/httpd" configfile="/etc/httpd/vip-151/httpd.conf" \
        op monitor interval=30s
```

I wanted to attach the corosync.log, but that took me over the limit of 30000 chracters for a question. So here is the one line that documents the failure (no saying it is the problem):

```
Mar 29 13:15:53  apache(vip_151_apache)[1897]:    ERROR: AH00180: WARNING: MaxRequestWorkers of 256 exceeds ServerLimit value of 100 servers, decreasing MaxRequestWorkers to 100. To increase, please see the ServerLimit directive. (99)Cannot assign requested address: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 10.49.4.151:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I think I made a minor mistake in the setup, but I surely cannot find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all.
Rudy

Comment: You could simplify the problem by having Apache listen on 0.0.0.0 and then control access as needed on each VIP at the firewall. Also, unrelated to your question, but a cluster should have an odd number of hosts to prevent a vote split during a failure.

Comment: I you discover how the "other cluster" is able to cheat crmd into registering a vip onto `lo` interface, it would be a valuable info. Please do not hesitate to self-answer how that is done. Normally a vip is only added to an interface if they are on the same IP subnet .

Answer (score 1):

In a corosync cluster Apache isn't going to run on each host, you need to bind it to the VIP resource so that it is only running on the active host, e.g.,

```
pcs constraint colocation add vip_151_apache vip_151 INFINITY
```

Or if you're only using `crmsh`

```
crm configure colocation apache_on_151 INFINITY: vip_151_apache vip_151
```